# How to make Ubuntu Alt+Tab smarter?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Alt+Tab is frequently used to switch windows under which a user is working parallel. But the more I use Alt+Tab under Ubuntu, the less I feel Ubuntu is smart. For example, when I am working in window A, I want to switch to window B, but most of the time ubuntu switch to another window C that I don't want to go to.

The question I want to ask is, is there a tool that can make Alt+Tab behaviour smarter?

My basic idea to make Alt+Tab smarter is that, the switching process can be modelled as a Markov process. That is using P_ij to represent the probability of switching from window i to window j. This matrix can be updated while I am working. A smarter Alt+Tab should be able to **guess** which window I want to go to according to this matrix.

However, I am idiot on programming to change this behaviour. Can you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea, but with the speed at which you open and close applications, a Markov chain might fail to keep up or create unecessary overhead. That being said, if you want to contribute I suggest reading here: [Giving Ideas and Feedback](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu#Giving_Ideas_and_Feedback). You don't need to program anything, but you do need to give it to the correct people who can.

This isn't the place, but I like where you are going with it.